# `getPlaceById` failed due to `places.get(0);` //Cannot resolve the method get(int)

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-places

I'm getting strange error from the  `mGeoDataClient.getPlaceById`.

Both `places.get(0);` and `places.release();` are not listed as member function of the `PlaceBufferResponse` class. Below code called at the end of `onMapReady`

```
mGeoDataClient.getPlaceById("ChIJS2ZUmz2uEmsR2scsVYE1u08").addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<PlaceBufferResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<PlaceBufferResponse> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                PlaceBufferResponse places = task.getResult();
                Place myPlace = places.get(0);
                Log.i("MAP", "Place found: " + myPlace.getName());
                places.release();
            } else {
                Log.e("MAP", "Place not found.");
            }
        }
    });
```

Using

```
api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
```

Any ideas to solve the issue?

Comment: `get(x)` is in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/PlaceBufferResponse), is there any chance you've got ProGuard enabled or are using a non-Google Maps `PlaceBufferResponse` somehow?

Comment: `com.google.android.gms.location.places.PlaceBufferResponse;` is imported and not grey. Proguard?

Comment: @JakeSteam minifyEnabled false

Comment: That's both my obvious ideas ruled out then, good luck!

Comment: @JakeSteam solved, no error for this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found my mistake after several hours. The API

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0
```

must be also in gradle dependencies.